# how to remove html doctype from ajax response result

Tags: ajax, salesforce, visualforce

I have a ajax function calls a visualforce page. the response returns a result with html doctype. I want only data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/apex/HotStuckLeadReportAjaxPage",
                data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                });
       });
```

output:

```
Data Saved: 

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


    {"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"2","iTotalDisplayRecords":"2","aaData":[["8","1","sdf","test","test"],["9","12","asdf","asdf","asdf"]]}</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add contentType in HotStuckLeadReportAjaxPage page

```
<apex:page  contentType="application/json">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can

1. simple skip first line
2. make sure your server do not SEND it.  String
3. Replace with Javascript the Exact DocType line, as it is often
   unchanged throughout the project.
4. Do a High class Regular expression
   remove [but it is same as string replace]